# Retrieve Average Disk Sec per transfer using WMI

Tags: powershell, wmi

I'm trying to retrieve average disk sec per transfer in ms. using the WMI. Below is the snippet. But i'm not doing the last minus the current using the below. Please advice how i can make this correct.

```
   Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk -Filter "NOT Name LIKE '_Total'" | ForEach-    Object { $y=((($_.AvgDiskSecPerTransfer/$_.Frequency_PerfTime)/$_.AvgDiskSecPerTransfer_Base)*1000) Write-Host "$_.name : $y"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just missed a `;` and had a few too many spaces:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk -Filter "NOT Name LIKE '_Total'" | ForEach-Object { $y=((($_.AvgDiskSecPerTransfer/$_.Frequency_PerfTime)/$_.AvgDiskSecPerTransfer_Base)*1000); Write-Host "$_.name : $y"}
```

On my system this returns:

```
\\CORSAIR-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk.Name="0 E:".name : 129.22604973848
\\CORSAIR-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk.Name="1 C:".name : 0.482442557684425
\\CORSAIR-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk.Name="2 D:".name : 1.79339154035152
\\CORSAIR-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk.Name="3 G:".name : 127.640155793976
\\CORSAIR-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk.Name="4 F:".name : 1.37056682368048
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a single sample in your formula. With raw counters you almost always need two. You can find the formula for `PERF_AVERAGE_TIMER` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804010.aspx)